# Proper type for imported components that don't share an interface implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

Trying to avoid having to type out the array multiple times:

```
import { ComponentA } from './components/A.component';
import { ComponentB } from './components/B.component';

const COMPONENTS: any[] = [
  ComponentA,
  ComponentB
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: COMPONENTS,
  exports: COMPONENTS
})
export class ExampleModule {
}
```

What is the appropriate type for `const COMPONENTS: any[]`? `any[]` works but we're trying to avoid usage of `any`, and `object[]` appears to work, but it feels like there should be something more specific and my search skills are failing me.

Comment: As an aside, I'd prefer not to use a marker interface if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything more specific for this. Since Components can essentially be an empty class, there is no real interface for them (same for pipes & directives).

If you look at the angular source code, you can see the NgModule interface defines declarations and exports as of having the type `Array<Type<any>|any[]>;`

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.6/packages/core/src/metadata/ng_module.ts#L115